# Javascript error - cannot call method 'appendChild' of null

Tags: javascript

I am new to Javascript (and programming in general) and have been trying to get a basic grasp on working with the DOM.  Apologies if this is a very basic mistake, but I looked around and couldn't find an answer.

I am trying to use the appendChild method to add a heading and some paragraph text into the  in the very basic HTML file below.

```
    <html> 
<head>
    <title>JS Practice</title>  
</head>
<body>
    <script src="script.js"></script> 
    <div id = "main">
        <h1>Simple HTML Page</h1>
        <p>This is a very simple HTML page.</p>
        <p>It's about as basic as they come. It has: </p>
        <ul>
            <li>An H1 Tag</li>
            <li>Two paragraphs</li>
            <li>An unordered list</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="javascript">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the js code:

```
var newHeading = document.createElement("h1"); 
var newParagraph = document.createElement("p"); 

newHeading.innerHTML = "New Heading!"; 
newParagraph.innerHTML = "Some text for a paragraph."; 

document.getElementById("javascript").appendChild(newHeading); 
document.getElementById("javascript").appendChild(newParagraph);
```

Running it causes an error: "Cannot call method 'appendChild' of null"

Help? I can't figure out why this isn't working...

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Assuming this code is inside the `script.js` file, this is because the javascript is running before the rest of the HTML page has loaded.

When an HTML page loads, when it comes across a linked resource such as a javascript file, it loads that resource, executes all code it can, and then continues running the page. So your code is running before the `<div>` is loaded on the page.

Move your `<script>` tag to the bottom of the page and you should no longer have the error. Alternatively, introduce an event such as `<body onload="doSomething();">` and then make a `doSomething()` method in your javascript file which will run those statements.

Answer (score 13):

There is an easier way to resolve this issue. Put your JavaScript inside of a function and use the window.onload. So for instance:

```
window.onload = function any_function_name()
{

var newHeading = document.createElement("h1"); 
var newParagraph = document.createElement("p"); 

newHeading.innerHTML = "New Heading!"; 
newParagraph.innerHTML = "Some text for a paragraph."; 

document.getElementById("javascript").appendChild(newHeading); 
document.getElementById("javascript").appendChild(newParagraph); 
}
```

Now, you do not have to move your  tag because that will run your code after the HTML has loaded.

Answer (score 9):

Your script is running before the elements are available.

Place your script directly before the closing `</body>` tag.

```
<html> 
<head>
    <title>JS Practice</title>  
</head>
<body>
    <div id = "main">
        <h1>Simple HTML Page</h1>
        <p>This is a very simple HTML page.</p>
        <p>It's about as basic as they come. It has: </p>
        <ul>
            <li>An H1 Tag</li>
            <li>Two paragraphs</li>
            <li>An unordered list</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="javascript">
    </div>

    <!-- Now it will run after the above elements have been created -->
    <script src="script.js"></script> 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I add an event listener to wait for DOM content to fully load

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    place_the_code_you_want_to_run_after_page_load
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Your DOM is not loaded, so **getElementById** will return null, use **document.ready()** in jquery

```
   $(document).ready(function(){

    var newHeading = document.createElement("h1"); 
    var newParagraph = document.createElement("p"); 

    newHeading.innerHTML = "New Heading!"; 
    newParagraph.innerHTML = "Some text for a paragraph."; 

    document.getElementById("javascript").appendChild(newHeading); 
    document.getElementById("javascript").appendChild(newParagraph); 

   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Because your JavaScript file is loaded first, and that time when you write `window.document.body.appendChild(btn)`, `body` element is not loaded in html, that's why you are getting error here, you can load the js file once body element is loaded in DOM.

**index.html**

```
<html>
     <head>
         <script src="JavaScript.js"></script>      
     </head>
     <body onload="init()">
          <h3> button will come here</h3>
     </body>
</html>
```

**JavaScript.js**

```
function init(){

   var button = window.document.createElement("button");

   var textNode = window.document.createTextNode("click me");

   button.appendChild(textNode);

   window.document.body.appendChild(button);

  }
```