# Creating html with javascript not working

Tags: javascript, html

I am attempting to create this with javascript so that i can repeat it as many times as I'd like

```
<div class="parallax-item">
<img src="http://freepngimages.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/bubble-transparent-background.png" alt="BUBBLE">
</div>
```

Here is the Javascript that I did, but when I run it nothing happens.

```js
var makeBubbles = function (numOfBubbles) {
      var div = document.createElement("div");
      div.className = "parralax-item";
      div.id = 'num' + numOfBubbles + 'div';
      document.getElementById("main").appendChild(div);
      var image = document.createElement("IMG");
      image.src = "http://freepngimages.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/bubble-transparent-background.png";
      image.alt = "BUBBLE";
      document.getElmentById('num' + numOfBubbles + 'div').appendChild(image);
      numOfBubbles --;
      if (numOfBubbles > 0) {
        makeBubbles(numOfBubbles);
      }
    };
    
    makeBubbles(9);
```

Where did i go wrong?
Also where could i see the changes that this makes to the html so that i could do some testing?

Comment: do you have a div with an id of main in your html doc?

Comment: Check out the inspection tool that Chrome has, it should help you see the HTML that is generated. I would also check the console to see where it is/isn't falling over. Lastly, is the code running before the div with id "main" is created?

Comment: Its a Typo: getElmentById should be getElementById

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30014090/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-appendchild-of-null)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got a **TypeError**, it is `getElementById`, not `getElmentById`

```js
var makeBubbles = function (numOfBubbles) {
      var div = document.createElement("div");
      div.className = "parralax-item";
      div.id = 'num' + numOfBubbles + 'div';
      document.getElementById("main").appendChild(div);
      var image = document.createElement("IMG");
      image.src = "http://freepngimages.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/bubble-transparent-background.png";
      image.alt = "BUBBLE";
      document.getElementById('num' + numOfBubbles + 'div').appendChild(image);
      numOfBubbles --;
      if (numOfBubbles > 0) {
        makeBubbles(numOfBubbles);
      }
    };
    
    makeBubbles(9);
```

```html
<div id="main"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems with your code

1. First there is no element with `id = main`.
2. You are using `document.getElmentById` missing `e`

See the working code

```js
var makeBubbles = function (numOfBubbles) {
      var div = document.createElement("div");
      div.className = "parralax-item";
      div.id = 'num' + numOfBubbles + 'div';
      document.getElementById("main").appendChild(div);
      var image = document.createElement("IMG");
      image.src = `http://freepngimages.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/bubble-transparent-background.png`;
      image.alt = "BUBBLE";
      document.getElementById('num' + numOfBubbles + 'div').appendChild(image);
      numOfBubbles --;
      if (numOfBubbles > 0) {
        makeBubbles(numOfBubbles);
      }
    };
    
    makeBubbles(9);
```

```html
<div id="main"></div>
```