# Adding table elements using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, html-table, element

Suppose I have a table of column product, rate this is the rows in it

```
<tr>
    <td>pepsi</td>
    <td>2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>juice</td>
    <td>4</td>
</tr>
```

I want total rate, example:

```
<tr>
     <td>total</td>
     <td>6</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: If it hard coded table? or you are getting values in response?

Comment: i want the values as response

Comment: As the values come in response, I strongly suggest you to calculate the sum on the responce object itself and then display on HTML instead of displaying table and then calculating sum by picking values form HTML.

Comment: Post you response in question if you need any further help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Get all last td of the table and get sum by iterating over them. Finally, generate the `tr` with the calculated sum.

```js
// variable for storing the sum
var sum = 0;
// get all last td from tr
// convert node list to array
// for old browser use `[].slice.call` instead
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('tr td:last-child'))
  // iterate over the td elements
  .forEach(function(e) {
    // calculate the sum based on the content
    sum += Number(e.textContent) || 0;
  })

// create tr element
var tr = document.createElement('tr');
// add first cell for showing text
tr.insertCell(0).textContent = 'total';
// add second column for sowing the calculated sum
tr.insertCell(1).textContent = sum;

// get the table and append the generated tr element
document.querySelector('table tbody,table').appendChild(tr);
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>pepsi</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>juice</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: thanks!! thats what I wanted

Comment: @peggy.go : glad to help

Comment: when a trying to add this to my code, it shows error in console "Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null". Do you know why?

Comment: @peggy.go : try `document.querySelector('table tbody,table').innerHTML`

Comment: still same "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of null"

Comment: @peggy.go :  oh sorry use `document.querySelector('table tbody,table').appendChild(tr)` ...still there is eeror then I think there is no `table` tag in your code.... the tr element should be child of `table`, `tbody` , `thead` or `tfoot`....

Comment: I found my silly mistake. I was adding script tag in the header. http://stackoverflow.com/a/8670572/6622173  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You can get all the rows of table by `table.rows` and loop through that to get cells values like below

```js
(function(){
var table = document.getElementById("mytab1");
var sum = 0;
for (var i = 0, row; row = table.rows[i]; i++) {
  sum += parseInt(table.rows[i].cells[1].innerHTML)
  // cells[1] is hardcoded (Assumed <td>2</td> will always the second cell your row)
}

var tr = document.createElement('tr');
tr.insertCell(0).textContent = 'total';
tr.insertCell(1).textContent = sum;
table.appendChild(tr);
})();
```

```html
<table id="mytab1">
  <tr>
      <td>pepsi</td>
      <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>juice</td>
      <td>4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `innerHTML`

```
table = document.getElementById('id_of_your_table');
table.innerHTML = table.innerHTML + '<tr><td>total</td><td>6</td></tr>';
```