# bodymovin in Angular4, fixing appendChild of undefined

Tags: javascript, angular, svg, bodymovin

I'm using the bodymovin script in my project. Even though some of my animated SVG's are rendering in the browser, I'm still getting this error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of undefined
    at SVGRenderer.configAnimation (bodymovin.min.js:5)
    at AnimationItem.configAnimation (bodymovin.min.js:9)
    at XMLHttpRequest.r.onreadystatechange (bodymovin.min.js:9)
    at XMLHttpRequest.wrapFn [as __zone_symbol___onreadystatechange] (zone.js:1075)
    at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:424)
    at Zone.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask (zone.js:191)
    at ZoneTask.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (zone.js:498)
    at invokeTask (zone.js:1370)
    at XMLHttpRequest.globalZoneAwareCallback (zone.js:1388)
```

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8670530/javascript-error-cannot-call-method-appendchild-of-null), I figure I should have the bodymovin script run after everything on the page has loaded. I've updated the code, taking into account the new suggestions

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>...</head>
<body>...
<div class="full-app-body">
   <app-root></app-root>
  </div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bodymovin/4.10.2/bodymovin.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component, ElementRef, OnInit, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute, RouterOutlet, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgClass, CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
...

export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  constructor(public router: Router, private elementRef: ElementRef) {}
...
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    const s = document.createElement('script');
    s.type = 'text/javascript';
    s.src = '/assets/js/animations.js';
    // this.elementRef.nativeElement.appendChild(s);
    document.body.appendChild(s);
  }
```

app.component.html

```
<div id='bm'></div>
```

animations.js

```
var animation = bodymovin.loadAnimation({
  container: document.getElementById('bm'),
  renderer: 'svg',
  loop: true,
  autoplay: true,
  path: './assets/images/ani/fatigue-data.json'
});
```

Comment: Where is the element with `bm` id?

Comment: updated the question -- the div is in app.component.html

Comment: please show where you are initializing this.elementRef

Comment: Try using `ngAfterViewInit` hook instead of `ngOnInit`

Comment: @yurzui I tried implementing AfterViewInit, and switching the code into the `ngAfterViewInit` but I'm still getting the same undefined error...

Comment: Set breakpoint and check what is undefined

Comment: @VikhyathMaiya I've added the line with the constructor

Comment: Your error is coming from `bodymoving.min.js`

Comment: @yurzui how would i go about troubleshooting that vendor file? I downloaded it exactly from [here](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bodymovin/4.10.2/bodymovin.min.js)

Comment: as far as i understand the issue is with the line this.elementRef.nativeElement.appendChild(s);.You are trying to append something to a unknown element.U should get reference to the element you are trying to attach the script to first.Where do you want s to be appended ?

Comment: @VikhyathMaiya Hmm... okay, that makes sense. How would I get a reference of the body, for example? I want to load in the script to the html body

Answer (score 1):

as far as i understand the issue is with the line `this.elementRef.nativeElement.appendChild(s);`.You are trying to append something to a unknown element.U should get reference to the element you are trying to attach the script to first. Since its just a matter of adding a script,try the following code

```
 document.body.appendChild(s);
```

Hope this will help

**update**

Since you are using angular 4,you can use Renderer2 for solving your purpose as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38088996/adding-script-tags-in-angular2-component-template?answertab=active#tab-top)

Comment: did it fix your issue ?